# Isekai manga, MC reads books that give him all magical knowledge, tames hundreds of slimes, kills a dragon, becomes an adventurer

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Basically the manga starts like this: dude wakes up in an old run down house filled with books which he reads, this gains him all magical knowledge of those books making him op but his mana can't withstand it (and and I believe it makes him faint) after using 1 spell which makes a massive mushroom cloud killed a dragon in the process, he also tames hundreds of slimes with a familiar spell.

Later on he goes to a small town and becomes an adventurer easily passing the test. Then a beast wave occurs and he sets up a barrier and kills all few thousand of the beasts. Afterwards he heads to a bigger town. (there is more to the story i just can't figure out how to phrase it) but later on traveling with 2 female adventurers through a canyon he kills an earth dragon and they spot a catastrophe class dragon from prophecies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where you read this?  Are there any details of the art (e.g. the way the characters are portrayed) or names of characters or places that you can recall?

Comment: These manga identification questions sometimes sound more like someone telling you about the dream they had last night.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tensei Kenja no Isekai Raifu ~Daini no Shokugyo wo Ete, Sekai Saikyou ni Narimashita* aka *[My Isekai Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Isekai_Life)* written by Shinkoshoto and illustrated by Huuka Kazabana.

[image: Front cover of My Isekai Life]

> Whether at the office or at home, corporate drone Yuji Sano works all the time. So when his home PC flashes a message about him being summoned to another world, Yuji restarts his machine ... only to find that he's inadvertently accepted the summons! Now in a fantasy world far removed from paperwork and computers, Yuji has just one thing on his mind: waking up from what he thinks is a dream and getting back to the mountain of work he left behind! But this other world has other plans for Yuji, who quickly discovers his Monster Tamer character class allows him to befriend slimes! And thanks to their number, those slimes help him absorb so much magical knowledge that he gains a second character class in the blink of an eye! How will Yuji wield his power now that he's the greatest sage the realm has ever known?! And what about all that paperwork?!

It doesn't match 100% since he first wakes up in the forest, then finds the house full of magic skill books, then tames 80 slimes at once, then kills the dragon.

Found with a search for `isekai manga learns magic kills dragon tames slimes`, which led me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/crci0y/searching_for_a_manga_about_a_slime_tamer_rmanga/).

[image: Finding the Grimoire] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

[image: Taming all the slimes] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

[image: Accidentally kills the dragon in one hit] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

[image: Used too much magic, negative MP and HP damage] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for, thank you

Comment: @DavidGitsham You can click on the check mark by the voting buttons to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't show up for me first time when i say your comment for me to do so, figured i needed to wait for it to show up but it's showing now and ive clicked it