# Isekai manga where the main character is accidentally killed by God and is then transported to another world as compensation

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for an Isekai manga I've read a long time ago. Here are some parts that I can remember:

1. The main character (MC) is a high schooler, aged 16-17, I believe.
2. The MC was accidentally killed by God and gets isekai'ed and given OP (overpowered) powers as compensation.
3. The 'god' is a generic old man with a long white beard.
4. As soon as the MC landed in the other world, he used enhancement magic on his body and ran around the forest he was transported to. His body took a toll due to the sudden enhancement and he was tired and had muscle cramps. (the most important and unique point, I think).
5. The MC looks like the generic black-haired MC; his design was kind of similar to Makoto from *Tsukimichi*.

I wish I could remember more, but I only read 1-2 chapters, since it was newly released back then. Also, thank you in advance for anyone who could help!

Comment: I agree that the cramps are the most unique aspect of this. Do you know if he died via Truck-Kun? Spontaneously exploded? Passed in his sleep?

Comment: Everything else in this question fits a dozen different Isekai!

Comment: Isekai Smartphone? MC is accidentally killed by God, resurrected into another world with obscenely powerful magical ability as compensation. And a smart phone that's still connected to our Internet. He figures out how to use it to cast even more powerful magic. I think he started out in a forest.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't really remember well, but I think he was struck by a stray lightning but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Shawn I've already checked Isekai Smartphone, it was actually the first one that popped when I searched 'accidentally killed by god' key word, and no it isn't it. They have different starts.

Comment: @Valorum would appreciate it if you can drop some few which fits them? Most importantly is that the mc get's muscle cramps from the bodily enhancement!

Comment: I do have a vague memory of an isekai manga where the main character got immediate access to several powerful spells, and one of the consequences was that the mana cost was greater than his reserve, causing him physical damage when he used the spells.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Ohh! Do you remember it's title?

Comment: *Tensei Kenja no Isekai Raifu ~Daini no Shokugyo wo Ete, Sekai Saikyou ni Narimashita* as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277382/isekai-manga-mc-reads-books-that-give-him-all-magical-knowledge-tames-hundreds/277384#277384. The framing doesn't work though. Sano is sent to the isekai world through a game prompt.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots tysm! I've checked it and it isn't it, I might try to watch/read this though!  ^^

It looks pretty interesting!

Answer (score 1):

IT'S SUDDEN, BUT I CAME TO ANOTHER WORLD! BUT I HOPE TO LIVE SAFELY

nvm its a lil different from what you said just MC deals with muscle cramps is unique so i thought i add it jic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If it's close enough it may still be worth posting; it's possible that OP has confused things with another manga and has mentioned something not actually in the one they are looking for.  You should add more details though, explaining exactly what matches and what doesn't.

Comment: Hmm... the God there does show up as a man with a white beard, but the protagonist is definitely not OP in the first chapter, barely surviving by running, and diagnosed as having as much mana as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In Another World With My Smartphone

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the question?

Comment: Having checked this manga myself, it seems to match the plot points numbered 1, 2, 3 and 5 in the question, but not the fourth one; no self-enhancement with magic, no running around a forest, and no muscle cramps in chapter 1, or chapters 2-5 for that matter.

Comment: OP has already ruled it out.